# How can I run Qiskit runtime program with Python package with C++ dependencies?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qiskit-runtime

Recently I was testing Python package on IBM Quantum Lab with Qiskit runtime programs. This package contain C++ and Eigen (C++ lib) dependencies. I don't have root permission so I cannot install it. How can I make it work on IBM platform or add it to custom runtime qiskit program?

Python package: https://github.com/BOBO1997/libs_qrem

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the bug report!
I am the developer of libs_qrem.
In the previous version, you have to install Eigen in advance, which may require root permission.

Now I added the Eigen library as a submodule to libs_qrem package.
Could you run the following command as shown in libs_qrem/README.md?

```
pip install git+https://github.com/BOBO1997/libs_qrem
```

Hope the current version works on your side:)